# Dev Container- Running container on remote host (Windows => Linux)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I have a problem trying to create the following:

- Developpers clone repo on their local Windows computer
- They launch the code with devContainer
- The container is on a remote linux VM
- Each developper has a dedicated folder on the VM where their code and data (vscode plugins, etc) are stored

The problem:
I launch the container successfuly, and connect to him however the folder `/app` only contains a folder `myRepo` which is empty.
I can't manage to copy my local code to the remote container

Is it possible to do what I want, and if it is, how should I edit my config ?

Thanks

I tried a lot of config, it seems that I manage to had a copy of my code with volume mount instead of bind ones, however I can't manage to use dedicated folder like I want.
Currently I have these config files:

`.devcontainer/devContainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "build": {
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile",
        "args": { "WORKSPACE": "/app" }
    },
    "workspaceFolder": "/app",
    "workspaceMount": "type=bind,source=/home/pc/docker_volumes/myName_data/,target=/app",
}
```

`DockerFile`

```
FROM node:21
ARG WORKSPACE
WORKDIR $WORKSPACE/myRepo
COPY . $WORKSPACE/myRepo

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

`.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "docker.environment": {
        "DOCKER_HOST": "ssh://image_dev"
    }
}
```

`image_dev` étant défini dans mon fichier config ssh